# How to use HttpWebRequest class for get real multiresponse

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I have some logic issues with [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.

I using `HttpWebRequest` class from `System.Net` namespace, and when I doing this:

```
while(true)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://somesite.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse responce = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

I get response one by one with overage one sec interval, but I think my internet connection can work faster because the received data is very small. Then I try this:

```
while(true)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse response = request.BeginGetResponse(EndReceive, obj);
}

internal void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    obj.Response = obj.Request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

And I get very small speed increasing, something about 10-30%, but I use async request, I send to server 5 request instead of one, why speed wasn't increase by more than 100%? 
It's ok if server can't handle more than one request from one ip at the same time... But when I run 10 console app with code:

```
void SendRequest()
{
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/") as HttpWebRequest;
    HttpWebResponse responce = request.BeginGetResponse(EndReceive, obj);
}

void EndReceive(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    obj.Response = obj.Request.EndGetResponse(ar) as HttpWebResponse;
}
```

I get speed increasing for like 4-8 times, is problem with `HttpWebRequest` class? And why i cant get such speed with one application but many async requests?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect you're basically being bounded by the built-in connection pool, which will limit the number of requests a single process (or possibly AppDomain) makes to a given host. If you want to change the number of concurrent requests you can make to a single host, use the [`<connectionManagement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb6y0fyc.aspx) element in your app.config.

As an aside, you should have a `using` statement when you use the response, otherwise you're not disposing of it properly... which can cause horrible problems with the connection pool in itself.